# How to get value from table where id of this value found on another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello every one I have two tables: 1) `acceptreq`, 2)  `needing`

I saved in `acceptreq` table `id` of operation and in `needing` table 
I want `time` , `bloodtype`  from `acceptreq` and `name`, `center`, `city` from `needing` table where `id` is the id of `time` and `bloodtype` in `acceptreq` 
how do I that in MySQL?

`acceptreq` table

```
|id|time|bloodtype|
|12|12:9|A+       |
```

`needing` table

```
|id|name|city|center|
|12|Asim|KH  |Istack|
```

I want get `name`, `time`, `city`, `bloodtype`, `center` of id 12 from the two tables.

Comment: you can use MySQL join

Comment: is 'id' field in second table is id of acceptreq table?

Comment: ya in second table and thank it solved @RohitGhotkar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `JOIN` on the `id` value:

```
SELECT n.name, a.time, n.city, a.bloodtype, n.center
FROM needing n
JOIN acceptreq a ON a.id = n.id AND a.id = 12
```

Output:

```
name    city    center  time    bloodtype
Asim    KH      Istack  12:9    A+
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/74heR1WVG6MLxnqovoeu2Q/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id,n.name,a.time,n.city,a.bloodtype,n.center 
from acceptreq as a inner join needing as n 
on a.id = n=id
where a.id = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

USE LEFT JOIN IF U WANT TO SHOW all acceptreq table

```
SELECT a.id,name,a.time,city,a.bloodtype,center FROM acceptreq a LEFT JOIN needing n ON a.id = n.id
```